# Firestore, Angular, AngularFire2 - Adding document with a reference type field

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is there a way to add a document with a reference type field to a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ... I made a mistake ... it's simple - we get a reference DocumentReference type (like *this.firestoreService.doc(ref).ref*) and store it in our object.

Comment: Can you provide more informations about having a reference field in a document ? Thanks